# Travis CI - Running Command on Job Cancellation

Tags: travis-ci

My team and I are currently building a project with Travis CI, which initiates a script on remote server.  When we click to cancel builds in the Travis UI, the Travis build stops but the script on the remote server continues to run.

Is it possible to automatically run a command after cancelling builds, so that we can tell the remote server to stop executing the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to Travis CI support for this email response:

> When a build or job is manually cancelled (or terminated by one of our
>   workers for a different reason) it is killed without any chance of
>   cleanup. So no, there is no special `after_cancelled` hook and
>   `after_failure` as well as `after_script` are not executed when
>   manually cancelling. This has to do with the way our build lifecycle
>   is implemented and making an `after_cancel` possible requires quite
>   some changes.
>
> We are aware of this issue. It has been raised in our public tracker
>   https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4221 and is also being
>   discussed internally. Unfortunately I cannot give you any time frame
>   when we will address this issue but we will update the public ticket
>   once there is progress.